# Not able to update geography field

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

I am attempting to update a Geography field in a table in SQL Server 2012.  After I execute the code below, no row is updated although the row does exist.

```
USE [LocalDb]
GO
DECLARE @latitude DECIMAL(15,6)
,@longitude DECIMAL(15,6)
,@Rec Int;
SET @Rec =(3);

SET @latitude =  (SELECT 51.4618933852762);
SET @longitude = (SELECT -0.926690306514502);
Print @longitude;
Print @latitude;
UPDATE GPSPositions
Set GeoColumn = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), 
@Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @Latitude) + ')', 4326)
WHERE ID = @Rec;
Go !-->
```

Are you able to assist with this please?

Comment: I noticed Microsoft uses `CAST` instead of `CONVERT` in their documentation of the STGeomFromText function. Maybe try that and see if it works. `CONVERT` may be putting the decimal values into the wrong format

Comment: Hi Tried your suggestion but the result is just the same!

Comment: I tested with both `CAST` and `CONVERT`, and they both seem to work correctly. What's the structure of your GPSPositions table, and do you have any sample data?

Comment: When you're saying "no row is updated", it's giving you `0 row(s) affected`? Or are you using some other heuristic? Also, I'd use the `geography::Point()` method rather than doing the STGeomFromText() dance that you're currently doing.

Comment: Hi Sorry it is working with the Change! Thank you for your comments.